# angularjs dynamic select in a form

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I'm developing an app where I retrieve from a server a JSON array that contains something like this:

```
[
    {"Day":"2016-11-18", "time":"09:00"},
    {"Day":"2016-11-18", "time":"15:20"},
    {"Day":"2016-11-19", "time":"10:30"},
    {"Day":"2016-11-19", "time":"12:00"},
    {"Day":"2016-11-21", "time":"15:40"},
    {"Day":"2016-11-21", "time":"17:50"}
]
```

And than i should create different arrays that contain all the different day, for example (2016-11-18, 2016-11-19, 2016-11-21) and another array that contains all the times but in the form when i selected a day the select of times should contains only the times belonging of that day.

I already have portions of code that work, i've the controller that retreive the JSON array from the server and i also have a portion of code that exctract days and times from the JSON array and sets the selects property.

**CONTROLLER**:

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.submit = function(){
        var link = 'http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/api.php';
        $scope.var = "stringa di prova";
        $http.post(link, {username : $scope.data.username}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });
        $scope.vm = this;

    };
});
```

**EXCTRACT FROM JSON**:

```
  angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  var events = [{
    "day": "11/17/2016",
    "time": "09:45"
  }, {
    "day": "17/11/2016",
    "time": "16:50"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "11:25"
  }, {
    "day": "18/11/2016",
    "time": "12:30"
  }, {
    "day": "11/21/2016",
    "time": "16:10"
  }, {
    "day": "11/21/2016",
    "time": "17:25"
  }];

  vm.data = processItems(events);

  function processItems(events) {
    var result = {
      events: [],
      schedules: []
    };

    var dates = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      if (dates.indexOf(events[i].day) === -1) {
        var date = events[i].day;
        dates.push(date);
        result.events.push({
          date: date
        });
      }

      result.schedules.push({
        date: events[i].day,
        time: events[i].time
      });
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Event Date</label>
      <select ng-options="event as event.date for event in ctrl.data.events" ng-model="ctrl.event">
        <option value="">Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Event Time</label>
      <select ng-options="schedule as schedule.time for schedule in ctrl.data.schedules | filter: { date: ctrl.event.date}" ng-model="ctrl.schedule" ng-disabled="!ctrl.event">
        <option value="">Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is, how can I insert the function for extract data from JSON in my controller?

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean inserting the function in your view?

Comment: I'm sorry I am like @BünyaminSarıgül, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: you can create a filter to convert the original array to an array with the distinct date

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül yes i would insert the function in my controller

Comment: Controller or view? To make it simpler, in js file or html?

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül pheraps is better to insert it in the html file

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo can you give me an example?